# Installing and Linking OpenCV 2.4.3 on 64 bit windows with CMake

Tags: windows, opencv, cmake

I am currently attempting to transition a CMake project from Linux to Windows that is dependent on OpenCV, but I'm having trouble linking the libraries to the executable.

I've posted the approximate CMakeLists.txt file below with some private stuff left out:

```
project(my_project_name)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-g -Wall")
SET(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/../bin)

FIND_PACKAGE(OpenCV REQUIRED)

IF(NOT OpenCV_FOUND)
    MESSAGE(FATAL_ERROR "OpenCV not found")
ENDIF()

SET(PROJECT_HDRS
    #headers here
)

SET(PROJECT_SRCS
    #sources here
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_SRCS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

This CMakeLists.txt file works just fine on Linux, but has trouble linking on Windows. My first instinct was that it was a bad install of OpenCV? Here are the approximate steps I used while installing OpenCV

1. Download OpenCV 2.4.3 executable (a self-extracting archive)
2. Extract to some directory
3. Use CMake-Gui to configure and generate OpenCV.sln
4. Open in Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express and build the ALL_BUILD project in Debug and Release configurations
5. Build the INSTALL project

When I try to build my own project, I get back the errors "undefined reference to 'cv::waitKey(int)' errors, which makes me think that it's a linker issue. I've attempted pointing to the .lib files directly, such as:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} C:/someDirectory/opencv_core243.lib)
```

but I still get back the same errors.

I've also attempted the methods in described in these StackOverflow threads:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417242/linking-problem-with-opencv-and-cmake) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502848/how-to-include-opencv-libraries-in-cmake-makefile).

I apologize beforehand if I'm missing something obvious, but this is more or less the first time I've developed on windows and I'm running out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

to my knowledge the problem is that `visual studio2010` or `vc++2010` comes with .`net framework 4.5`

Downgrade it to `.net framework4` (i.e. uninstall `.net 4.5` and install `4.0`).
That would solve the problem...
I hit my head to my table solving the above problem..
or else 
patch the `visual c++` with new Service pack

Answer (score 0):

it´s a little bit late but... let´s go

for me this tutorial was perfect

http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/